# New Tag for Code-Modifying Challenges

Tags: discussion, tags

We currently have 4 [King](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/36978/whats-wrong-with-public-variables) [of](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/37308/codebots-2-event-driven-design) [the](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/36645/brainfedbotsforbattling-a-brainf-tournament?rq=1) [Hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/47581/the-nano-core-war?rq=1) challenges that involve modifying opponent's code in order to win.

They are quite unique, and in hopes that people will create more of them, I think it is a good idea to create a tag for it.

Should we create a tag for these types of challenges, and if so, what should the tag be?

Answer (score 14):

There shouldn't be a tag, because of any of the following:

- There aren't enough challenges
- It is too specific of a category
- Other reasons?

Comment: -1, (I can't vote)

Comment: I agree, since there aren't enough yet, but I think we should encourage the addition of challenges intended to teach users about self-modifying code. I, for one, don't know much about it.

Comment: I think self-modifying code and code that modifies opponent code would be very different categories. I can't think of a meaningful tag name for opponent-modifying code.

Comment: @trichoplax I'd call it "code-wars" since that's kind of what it is, and it sounds like "Core Wars", which is the first occurrence of that sort of challenge that I know of...

Comment: I'm not sure that "code-wars" makes it sufficiently clear that this doesn't include all KotH challenges.

Answer (score -4):

We should create a tag [source-battle](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/source-battle).

Answer (score -7):

We should use the tag [code-fight](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-fight)